# SIM900 error 601 when sending a second POST

Tags: http, sim900

**Using SIM 900** :

`AT+HTTPINIT`

`AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1`

`AT+HTTPPARA="URL","www.onewebsite.fr"`

`AT+HTTPDATA=lengthofpostdata, 10000`

sending data

`AT+HTTPACTION=1`

`AT_HTTPREAD=0, lengthofreceiveddata`

**Up to that point everything works OK**

**Then i send a new request :**

`AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1`

`AT+HTTPPARA="URL","www.onewebsite.fr"`

`AT+HTTPDATA=lengthofpostdata, 10000`

sending data

`AT+HTTPACTION=1`

**Then I received the message :** `+HTTPACTION=1,601,0`

Any idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [error +HTTPACTION:0,601,0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975051/error-httpaction0-601-0)

Comment: Not a duplicate, because setting up of connection bearer was already done (even if not described here) and because the first transaction (POST) worked successfully. The concern if for the second POST request.

Comment: I send commands repeatedly with the following set (I don't send the CID again): HTTPPARA=URL, HTTPACTION=0 (http get instead of post), HTTPREAD.  This generally works, but sometimes I get a 60x error.  I'm thinking of upgrading the firmware...

Answer (score 4):

601 is some custom implemented Error code, as an example

> This is a "magic" status code that we use to signal that something wrong happened with the request that was so bad that we didn't even got a response back from the server. In this case the request timed out (more than 30 seconds to return any bytes).

[source](https://forums.iis.net/post/1968716.aspx)

[Here](http://httpstatus.es/) is the list of standard [HTTP Status codes](http://httpstatus.es/)

At times you would get this error if you are sending requests too often as well! try to increase the delay between the two requests!

---

**. +HTTPACTION:0,601,0**

> The above AT response code (601) for HTTP session start indicates that
>   there is a network error. Then make sure that the PDP context is setup
>   properly.

[source](https://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/at-command-for-http-functions-for-remote-server-data-access/)

Comment: What are you quoting there?

Comment: I answered it long back and forgot to put the source . I found it and updated the answer as well

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem and the solution is to open the bearer again before the second request.
Use

```
AT+SAPBR=1,1https://stackoverflow.com/questions
```

Answer (score 0):

Some steps I have found to work:

1. Use the Adafruit FONA library if possible
2. Before every HTTP request check whether GPRS is enabled
3. If GPRS is enabled, check whether you have been assigned an IP Address
4. If 2 and 3 are true, proceed to make the HTTP request. If not, try to reconnect to GPRS until 2 and 3 are true