# Sim 800 +HTTPACTION: 0,601,0

Tags: http, at-command, sim800

I'm trying to get a gprs connection to a server by using a sim 800 module.

I'm getting 601 errors.
I have tried the debbuging that are described in this question: [error +HTTPACTION:0,601,0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975051/error-httpaction0-601-0)

```
AT

OK
ATZ

OK
AT+CFUN=1

OK
AT+CPIN?

+CPIN: READY

OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"

OK  
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","internet.t-d1.de"

OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"USER","t-mobile"

OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"PWD","tm"

OK
AT+SAPBR=1,1

OK
AT+SAPBR=2,1

+SAPBR: 1,1,"37.83.19.125"

OK
AT+HTTPINIT

OK
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1 

OK
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","https://mrgames-server.de/vehicle_safe/get.php?command=test"

OK
AT+HTTPACTION=0

OK

+HTTPACTION: 0,601,0
AT+HTTPREAD

OK
AT+HTTPTERM
```

Has anyone ever done this sucessfully?

Comment: `+HTTPACTION:0,601,0` is network error. Some basic checkup will resolve the issue. Check your simcard GPRS activation. Check your Antenna.

Comment: have you solved your issue?

Comment: @zhekaus No I did not solve it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69513173/8119511

Answer (score 2):

I've learned that if you want to make a request to HTTPS websites, you need to use `At+HTTPSSL=1`. However, i'm trying to do the same, make a request to a https server and it's not working. I'm only getting 606/601/606 responses.

Also, remember, SIM800 only supports TSL1.0, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

you should follow instructions that is written by SIMCOM itself.

https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/sim800_series_ip_application_note_v1.00.pdf

If you get network error 0,601,0, you can follow instructions under HTTP Get Post header. However, the only thing that you should do is putting AT+SAPBR=0,1 to end of the command sequence. Do your http configurations first, get http data from the url, and deact the process using AT+SAPBR=0,1. Moreover, in the application note you will notice that APN is configures as CMNET. You can try this, hopefully it is going to work.

Comment: You are an absolute legend! AT+SAPBR=0,1 at the END of the sequence was what solved it for me.